# Spring-Data JPA query method names for joined entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, crud

I have two entities:

1. `User` (it has field `String userName`);
2. `School` (it has field `Long id`);

In `School` I have:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = User.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "schoolId")
private List<User> users;
```

In `User` I have:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, targetEntity = School.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "schoolId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private School school;
```

I also have `SchoolRepository`:

```
public interface SchoolRepositoryextends CrudRepository<School, Long> {
}
```

And I want to make a request to database by `JPA` query method names. For example, I want to find all users with name `John` in school with `id = 1`.
How can I do this via `SchoolRepository`?

The only thing that comes to my mind is `findByIdAndUsersUserName`, but it gives me the exception that there's no field named `users` in my `schools` table.

NOTE:

of course, it is possible via `@Query` but I wonder if there's a way to do it via `method names`.

Comment: are you referring to spring data jpa? https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details

Comment: Indeed, that is not the JPA API. It is SPRING. SPRING DATA JPA != JPA API

Comment: Yes, you're right, thank you.

Comment: You can do it only in UsersRepository. selectByNameAndSchool

Comment: @DenB `And` keyword is for `and`ing the multiple condition for where. check 6.3.2 from https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.repositories